# What's the difference between 我住在 and 還活著?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, characters

I think both **我住在** and **還活著** have quite the same meaning (*I'm alive*), can I use evenly one of them as I like or are there some rules that force me to distinguish their use according to different contexts?

Comment: 我住在 doesn't mean *I'm alive*, it means *I live at (some place)*.

Answer (score 4):

They are two different things;

我住在 = "I live in/ at" - e.g.  我住在香港 (I live in Hong Kong)

還活著 = "still alive" - e.g. 我還活著 (I am still alive)

Comment: Ah ok, my mistake. If I can't repeat 還活著 in a text, are there any other forms to write it with the very same meaning?

Comment: @reasonable doubt  仍 or 尚 can replace 還 as 'still' ; 沒死 (not dead) or 生存著 (alive) can replace 活著

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are confusing with the phrase xx还在 to mean xx is still alive.

我爷爷还在 my grandpa is still alive / 我爷爷不在了 my grandpa is dead.

This phrase is more formal than 还活着/死了